# WPF C# DataTrigger Binding to OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, propertychanged

I'm trying to create a DataTrigger which changes the style of a border whenever a certain property is changed. I've created the property and I'm calling the PropertyChanged event and it works perfectly fine with other XAML components, but for some reason, it won't work with my DataTrigger.

XAML File:

```
<Style x:Key="InputParameterBorder" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource ParameterBorder}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayGradient}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- This changes input color -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Parameter, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YellowGradient}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

C# File:

```
    private IInputParameter _parameter;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public IInputParameter Parameter
    { get
        {
            return _parameter;
        }
        set
        {
            _parameter = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Parameter"));
        }

    }
```

EDIT: I changed InputParameter to Parameter in the Binding method, but it still doesn't work.

EDIT 2: Added XAML code with the implementation of InputParameterBorder.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InputParameterBox">
        <Border Style="{StaticResource InputParameterBorder}" 
                AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="InputParameter_DragEnter" Drop="InputParameter_Drop" 
                MouseLeftButtonDown="InputParameter_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parameter.Type}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource InputParameterTypeLabel}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parameter.Name}"  Style="{StaticResource InputParameterNameLabel}" />
            </Grid>
            <!--TextBlock Text="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource WorkflowParameterTypeConverter}}" -->
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And implementation of InputParameterBox:

```
<DataTemplate>
             <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding InputParameters}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InputParameterBox}">
                  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="200" />
                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your are binding to "InputParameter", but in your ViewModel ,you have a property named "Parameter". That could be your problem.

Comment: Besides that, you should also check if PropertyChanged is null: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Parameter)));`

Comment: I also doubt that you actually need your IsNullConverter. You could use `Value="{x:Null}"` in the DataTrigger.

Comment: And the DataContext of the styled Border (or one of its parent elements) is set to an instance of the class with the Parameter property?

Comment: Could you show us how you apply this style in your xaml?

Comment: Based on your update try to put the style in the `<DataTemplate.Resources>` tag. Or add another style in there that is based on your style with trigger.